# Squid3 Access Denied error

Tags: proxy, squid

I have set up a VPS on DigitalOCean and installed squid3. 
Here is the tail of the /etc/squid3/squid.conf file:

```
acl myhost src 1.2.3.4 # 1.2.3.4 is replaced by my ip at whatismyipaddress.com
http_access allow myhost

via off
forwarded_for off

request_header_access Allow allow all 
request_header_access Authorization allow all 
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all 
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all 
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all 
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all 
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all 
request_header_access Content-Length allow all 
request_header_access Content-Type allow all 
request_header_access Date allow all 
request_header_access Expires allow all 
request_header_access Host allow all 
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all 
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all 
request_header_access Location allow all 
request_header_access Pragma allow all 
request_header_access Accept allow all 
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all 
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all 
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all 
request_header_access Content-Language allow all 
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all 
request_header_access Retry-After allow all 
request_header_access Title allow all 
request_header_access Connection allow all 
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all 
request_header_access User-Agent allow all 
request_header_access Cookie allow all 
request_header_access All deny all
```

But no matter what I try I keep on getting access denied error.

> ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://www.google.com/search?
>
> ```
> Access Denied.
> ```
>
> Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed
>   at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is
>   incorrect.
>
> Your cache administrator is webmaster.

What is the reason?

Comment: Did you actually replace 1.2.3.4 with your actual IP?

Comment: Yes, I did that.

Comment: Did you restart Squid after that? What does /var/log/squid/cache.log say when you try and access a website?

Comment: Finally I was able to fix it. There were some deny all in the default configuration, which I just hashed. But now I have got another problem:
Squid doesn't load the page completely, is that because of low timeout. How to set that?